# How to get a bone’s Pose Mode transform matrix

Tags: python, bones, pose-mode, matrix

With my script I want to export these values for bones:

[image]

I have tried using `PoseBone.matrix_basis` but I got incorrect values. For instance the expected quaternion rotation is (1,0,0,0) after export it is (0,707107, -0,707107, -0,707107, -0,707107). Can someone help me out please ?

Answer (score 2):

The `PoseBone.matrix_basis` attribute works as expected. Use the matrix's `decompose` method to extract the quaternion rotation.

To test the script, open up a new file, delete everything and create an *armature*.

```
import bpy

for b in bpy.context.scene.objects.active.pose.bones:
    # use the decompose method
    loc, rot, sca = b.matrix_basis.decompose()
    # or use the to_quaternion method
    rot = b.matrix_basis.to_quaternion()

    print(rot)
```

Result: **`<Quaternion <w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000>>`**

If you want to use the matrix for other things you can easily make a copy with the `matrix.copy()` method.

Comment: Yes I decimpose the matrix before I print out, but here I got those incorrect values. I don't know why. I would share the full script but it is a private project so I can't.

Comment: @Vettel.Sebastion Ok, but the the `matrix_basis` attribute works as expected. It must be some other part of your script, which causes the unexpected behaviour. I'd try to condense the script in question to the core lines (untill it doesn't reveal anything private) and the share it.

Comment: @Leander could also use `matrix.to_quaternion()`  Going by the 1 over root 2 nature of the rotation in question could be the exporter is rotating to convert from bone y up to some other axis.  Anyhoo it's all too secret squirrel so we may never find out.

Comment: I realised that the values go wrong because before the decompose I multiply the matrix basis with axis_change which is: `axis_change = mathutils.Matrix(
                        ((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                         (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
                         (0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                         (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))`   is there a way to change the axis order without causing the broken values ?